# Nginx 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, nodejs

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

and my node app is listening on port 8081 too. Ideas on what it might be or more information needed?